# USB driver tests on embedded linux device

Tags: linux, usb, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, libusb

I am looking for and open source test suite to test the USB drivers on an embedded linux device. Any suggestions are welcome ? I am reading through this link : http://www.linux-usb.org/usbtest/

If any open suite USB test suite does not exist can someone suggest some ideas on testing the USB on an embedded device please  ?

Comment: You might want to mention what type of usb interface it has - ie, host, device, otg, and what type of functionality it supports (mass storage, networking, etc).

Comment: How do I find the usb interface ? It supports mass storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the [Linux Test Project](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/). In their [tool matrix](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/tooltable.php) **usbstress** is listed. You could also extend LTP to support more USB tests...